# Add white spaces between tables whose are in panel

Tags: c#, panel

I work with `ASP.NET` and want to create some tables in panel. So, I need to add white spaces between tables. I tried to create label and add it after each table, but it does not work.

```
Label label = new Label();
label.Text = Environment.NewLine;
panel.Controls.Add(label);
```

Comment: You can use CSS margins

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this a number of ways one is insert a div element and set the style attribute with the dimensions, also if you use the div make sure you set the innerText/innerHTML to &nbsp; (space) as some browsers won't display empty divs. The other way is to set the style attribute of the table's margin property to the required space as.

```
table.Attributes.Add("style", "margin-left:10px; margin-top:20px;");
```

Answer (score -3):

I prefer to add a `border-right: 5px solid white;` to all elements.

Comment: What do you do, if your background is not white? Border is simple wrong, and `margin-right: 5px;` or `padding-right: 5px;` is not only shorter, it's also the correct way.